# Не получается допилить раскрытие текста по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.service-block__card-open').click(function(){
    $(this).next('#var').slideToggle('normal');
    return false;
  });
  $('.service-block__card-close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('#var').slideToggle('normal');
  });
  $('a.show').on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide();
    return false;
  });
  $('a.hide').on('click', function(){
    $('a.show').slideDown("slow");
    $(this).show();
    return false;
  });
```

```
          <div class="service-block__card" id="card">
            <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Строительство домов</h1>
            <div class="service-block__card-img">
              <img src="img/service/service-1.jpg" alt="service-1">
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="service-block__card-text">
              <p>Какой дом вы хотите иметь? Каменный или деревянный? Вы уже определи ли для себя бюджет будущей застройки?</p>
              <p>Всё строительство условно можно разделить на капитальное и низкобюджетное.</p>
              <p>К низкобюджетному относятся щитовые постройки. Их сложно назвать экологичными и практичными. Мы этого касаться не будем. Наша компания занимается капитальным строительством из бруса, бревна, блоков и кирпича.</p>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="service-block__card-open show">Развернуть</a>
              <div id="var">
                <p>Подробно о ценах в разделе «прайс».</p>
                <p>Если делать сравнительную характеристику стеновых материалов, несомненно, выиграет кирпич. Но в силу дороговизны постройки, уступает своё место блочным материалам: пеноблоку, газобетону и керамзитобетону. Блоки – сравнительно новый материал. Значительно дешевле, не требуют широкой кладки, имеют большие размеры и хорошие эксплуатационные характеристики. За последнее время для строительства загородных домов под ключ в Москве и Подмосковье всё чаще применяются именно блоки.</p>
                <p>Дома из дерева – самое экологичное жильё. Наиболее подходящий вариант для жизни и отдыха.</p>
                <p>Интересует строительство загородного дома под ключ в Подмосковье?</p>
                <p>Мы занимаемся индивидуальными застройками с 2004 года.</p>
                <p>Опыт и профессионализм наших сотрудников к вашим услугам!</p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="service-block__card-close hide">Свернуть</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Скрипт в принципе работает, происходит следующее, я нажимаю на развернуть, разворачивается блок, но! у меня этих карточек 5 штук, и проблема в том, что когда допустим 2 карточки развернуты и я нажимаю на "Свернуть" У меня "Развернуть" появляется во всех развернутых карточках, я даже знаю где конь зарыт, вот в этом блоке я пытался через this обратиться именно к одной карточке

```
$('a.hide').on('click', function(){
    $('a.show').slideDown("slow");
    $(this).show();
    return false;
  });
```

вот в общем-то, не знаю как облагородить.

полный код html скраницы:

```
<main>
    <section class="service">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="service-block">
          <div class="service-block__card" id="card">
            <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Строительство домов</h1>
            <div class="service-block__card-img">
              <img src="img/service/service-1.jpg" alt="service-1">
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="service-block__card-text">
              <p>Какой дом вы хотите иметь? Каменный или деревянный? Вы уже определи ли для себя бюджет будущей застройки?</p>
              <p>Всё строительство условно можно разделить на капитальное и низкобюджетное.</p>
              <p>К низкобюджетному относятся щитовые постройки. Их сложно назвать экологичными и практичными. Мы этого касаться не будем. Наша компания занимается капитальным строительством из бруса, бревна, блоков и кирпича.</p>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="service-block__card-open show">Развернуть</a>
              <div id="var">
                <p>Подробно о ценах в разделе «прайс».</p>
                <p>Если делать сравнительную характеристику стеновых материалов, несомненно, выиграет кирпич. Но в силу дороговизны постройки, уступает своё место блочным материалам: пеноблоку, газобетону и керамзитобетону. Блоки – сравнительно новый материал. Значительно дешевле, не требуют широкой кладки, имеют большие размеры и хорошие эксплуатационные характеристики. За последнее время для строительства загородных домов под ключ в Москве и Подмосковье всё чаще применяются именно блоки.</p>
                <p>Дома из дерева – самое экологичное жильё. Наиболее подходящий вариант для жизни и отдыха.</p>
                <p>Интересует строительство загородного дома под ключ в Подмосковье?</p>
                <p>Мы занимаемся индивидуальными застройками с 2004 года.</p>
                <p>Опыт и профессионализм наших сотрудников к вашим услугам!</p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="service-block__card-close hide">Свернуть</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.service-block__card -->
          <div class="service-block__card" id="card">
            <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Реконструкция домов</h1>
            <div class="service-block__card-img">
              <img src="img/service/service-2.jpg" alt="service-2">
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="service-block__card-text">
              <p>Это сложный процесс, подразумевающий переустройство с перепланировкой, надстройками - значительными изменениями, способными до неузнаваемости всё изменить. Не стоит путать с капитальным ремонтом.</p>
              <p>Процесс это довольно трудоёмкий и затратный. Несущие конструкции постройки могут быть сильно изношены и требовать их усиления или замены.</p>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="service-block__card-open show">Развернуть</a>
              <div id="var">
                <p>В процессе реконструкции всегда возникает множество </p>
                <p> индивидуальных моментов, не зависимо от вида дома: кирпичного, брусового, бревенчатого, требующих высокого мастерства исполнителей.</p>
                <p>«Краски Жизни» на рынке строительных услуг с 2004 года. У нас накоплен большой опыт работы с объектами любой сложности.</p>
                <p>За качеством – к профессионалам!</p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="service-block__card-close hide">Свернуть</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.service-block__card -->
          <div class="service-block__card" id="card">
            <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Внутренняя отделка дома</h1>
            <div class="service-block__card-img">
              <img src="img/service/service-3.jpg"  alt="service-3">
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="service-block__card-text">
              <p>Отличие внутренней отделки каменного загородного дома от городской квартиры заключается в утеплении перекрытий, крыши, монтаже электрики, заземления и молниезащиты.</p>
              <p>Внутренняя отделка деревянного загородного дома имеет ряд особенностей. Связано это со способностью древесины поглощать и выделять влагу. Большинство людей предпочитают сохранить</p>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="service-block__card-open show">Развернуть</a>
              <div id="var">
                <p> натуральность древесины, выполнив шлифовку с последующей пропиткой. В доме из нестроганого бруса можно выполнить отделку вагонкой, имитацией бруса или блокхаусом.</p>
                <p>Наши клиенты получают:</p>
                <p>Выполнение работ любой сложности мастерами с высокой квалификацией;</p>
                <p>Гарантию от компании с большим опытом;</p>
                <p>Консультацию на всех этапах работы;</p>
                <p>Помощь в подборе материалов.</p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="service-block__card-close hide">Свернуть</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.service-block__card -->
          <div class="service-block__card" id="card">
            <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Утепление дома</h1>
            <div class="service-block__card-img">
              <img src="img/service/service-4.jpg" alt="service-4">
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="service-block__card-text">
              <p>Утеплить – значит свести к минимуму потери тепла, выполнить пароизоляцию, ветро-гидроизоляцию и шумоизоляцию одновременно. Задуматься об этом стоит ещё на стадии проектирования дома. С чем работаем:</p>
              <ol>
                <li>Стены. Именно здесь идут самые большие теплопотери. Все работы лучше вести снаружи;</li>
                <li>Перекрытия (пол, потолок);</li>
                <li>Крыша.</li>
              </ol>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="service-block__card-open show">Развернуть</a>
              <div id="var">
                <p>Какие материалы используем:</p>
                <ol>
                  <li>Минераловатные на базальтовой основе (экологически чистые, дышащие материалы);</li>
                  <li>Пеноплекс и пенополистирол (синтетические, не мокнут и не гниют). Ими выполняют утепление дома снаружи;</li>
                  <li>Пенные (пенополиуретан и эковата).</li>
                </ol>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="service-block__card-close hide">Свернуть</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.service-block__card -->
          <div class="service-block__card" id="card">
            <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Электрика</h1>
            <div class="service-block__card-img">
              <img src="img/service/service-5.jpg" alt="service-5">
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="service-block__card-text">
              <p>Все понимают, что электрика – дело ответственное, сопряжённое с безопасностью и одновременно комфортом проживания.</p>
              <p>Электропроводка может быть устроена двумя способами:</p>
              <ul>
                <li>Закрытым. Прячется внутри стен и перекрытий, не портит внешнего вида. Наиболее часто применяется в жилых помещениях;</li>
                <li>Открытым. Располагается на поверхности стен и потолков, расположена в специальных коробах, может быть вмонтирована в плинтуса.</li>
              </ul>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="service-block__card-open show">Развернуть</a>
              <div id="var">
                <p>Электромонтаж в городской квартире и каменном загородном доме имеют много общего. Отличительные особенности для каменной загородной постройки:</p>
                <ol>
                  <li>Обязательное устройство заземления;</li>
                  <li>Устройство молниезащиты;</li>
                  <li>Обязательное применение устройств защитного отключения.</li>
                </ol>
                <p>Монтаж электропроводки в деревянном доме имеет свои особенности. Сопряжено это с высокой пожароопасностью. Прежде всего, надо правильно рассчитать расчет нагрузок, исходя из него, подобрать кабель. Прокладка проводки внутри деревянных стен и перекрытий должна проводиться только в металлической трубе.</p>
                <p>Хотите жить комфортно? Ответственно относитесь к безопасности проживания?</p>
                <p>Выбирайте профессионалов!</p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="service-block__card-close hide">Свернуть</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.service-block__card -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.service-block -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.service -->
  </main>
```

[для наглядности, ссылка на сайт](http://mytrueblog.site/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9/)

Comment: добавьте полный код вашей страницы

Comment: добавил секцию со всеми карточками, так подойдет?

Comment: также закинул все на хостинг для наглядности
ссылка под темой

Comment: Ну у вас ничего не изменилось, тот код который я писал в предыдущем вопросе нормально работает, вы просто используете не те методы, изучите их подробнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.show').click(function() {
  $(this).hide().next('.var').slideDown().find('.hide').show();
});

$('.hide').click(function() {
  $(this).hide().closest('.var').slideUp().prev('.show').show();
});
```

Код решивший задачу.